# How to interpret the results of an epoch in Deep Learning?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

Would you please advice how to interpret the results of an epoch; loss and val_loss, their differences with each other and also with other epochs?

An output as an example:

[image: An output as an example]

Comment: please provide an example for above.

Answer (score 0):

"In machine-learning parlance, an epoch is a complete pass through a given dataset." taken from https://deeplearning4j.org/glossary

Whereas an iterations is for example a mini batch

loss is the actual error based on the measure you've specified, the lower the better. Or in other words, how good does the neural network fit the data

val_loss is the same, but not on the training but on the validation data set, I assume you are taking about keras...

COMMENT ON THE FIGURE:

So since your loss is not decreasing over time I'd try the following:

- increase learning rate
- increase size of neural network (layers, neurons)
- train for longer

Since loss and val_loss are pretty the same this means you are not overf-itting, but it seams you are not learning at all

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just to be more clarified, would you please give some explanations on the figure which I added?

Comment: Loss *is* decreasing, albeit slowly; and we don't know if the plots shown are the loss or some score like accuracy (I suspect the second). @MohsenHaghaieghshenasfard before asking for explanations, what about yourself providing details on what exactly you are showing here??

Comment: As @RomeoKienzler explained, I would like to interpret the output in a way that I link it to the related hyperparameters and change them more intuitively, but not with trial and error. In my opinion, it would be very helpful if there would be a function to analyze the output and give some basic feedback on the network (AutoML) based on what Romeo mentioned. Thus, less iteration is needed towards a greener earth.

Comment: @MohsenHaghaieghshenasfard didn't ask for that; I said that, before asking us to help you interpret etc, you must first explain clearly *what is that you want interpreted/explained?* What are you showing in the plots?? Is it accuracy? Loss? Something else?? What is included in `predictions1.scores`??